# Why containers network throughput is low

Tags: performance, networking, throughput, docker, lxc

I created a couple of containers using Dockers and measured the network performance by means of Netperf. However the throughput results to be quite low, around 563.81 Mb/s. Isn't the communication between 2 containers/processes done through main memory? Does anyone have an idea why I am having such a low throughput. Do I need a specific configuration?

Thanks,
Genc

Comment: Maybe you could share how you concluded that it's slow. Like your docker files etc.. Some output, hardware, etc.. It all seems very YMMV.

Comment: It would be useful to know which kernel version you are running; and if you are running on bare metal or within a VM. THank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question has been asked on the `docker-user` mailing list, and after some investigation, we found out that performance of `veth` in VMs with kernel 3.8 was "not great", and was significantly improved with kernel 3.10.

In other words:

- if you run containers on bare metal, you will be fine (and see very fast transfer speeds between containers), regardless of the kernel version that you are using;
- if you run containers in a VM (tested with Xen, VirtualBox, and KVM), you might see a huge drop in container-to-container transfer speed, if you run with kernel up to 3.8;
- if you run kernel 3.10 or above, performance will be fine, regardless of the setup.

We haven't pinpointed the source of the problem yet, though.

Comment: i had same problem with docker on VM for mac. really not ideal for development. :(